# Передача в ApacheFOP потока

Tags: java, c#, .net

Здравствуйте, для преобразования файлов из формата XSL-FO в формат PDF используется следующий код, работающий с подключенными пакетами IKVM и FOP:

```
using org.apache.fop.tools;
using org.apache.fop.apps;
using org.xml.sax;
using java.io;

public void PDF(string inpFile, string pdfFile)
{
    OutputStream os = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new java.io.File(pdfFile)));

    try
    {
        FopFactory fopFactory = FopFactory.newInstance();
        Fop fop = fopFactory.newFop("application/pdf", os);
        FOUserAgent foUserAgent = fop.getUserAgent();
        javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory factory = javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        javax.xml.transform.Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer();
        javax.xml.transform.Source src = new javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource(new java.io.File(inpFile));
        javax.xml.transform.Result res = new javax.xml.transform.sax.SAXResult(fop.getDefaultHandler());
        transformer.transform(src, res);
    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {                
        throw ex;
    }

    finally
    {
        os.close();
    }
}
```

Переменная inpFile передает путь до файла формата XSL-FO. Как сделать так, чтобы inpFile передавал файл через MemoryStream в StreamSource?

UPD: Я имею ввиду, как реализовать передачу потока, когда значению параметра в методе уже присвоен тип Memorystream, т.е. стоит PDF(Memorystream inpFile, string pdfFile). И если его просто передать в javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource(inpFile), то выводится ошибка т.к. данный класс требует строковое значение параметра.

Answer (score 0):

Например так,

```
Source source = new StreamSource(new StringReader(foString));
transformer.transform(source, res);
```

Comment: Не совсем то, что я имел ввиду - разъяснил в первом сообщении.

Comment: Чем не устраивает? В приведённом примере вы передаёте в конструктор SteramSource содержимое файла в виде строки, которая может быть сформирована любым удобным вам способом. Наличе настоящего файла вовсе не обязательно.

Comment: Потому что в строковый тип данных можно поместить массив только определенной длины. Что делать с файлами, которые содержат текст большей длины - неизвестно (хотя вряд ли файлы такой длины встретятся, но в идеале нужно и это предусмотреть). Когда объем массива в MemoryStream ограничен только оперативной памятью...

Comment: "массив только определенной длины" - не знаю как там в C#, но в Java это около 2GB. Ну, если файл реально существует где-то в файловой системе, то можно ещё построить StreamSource из потока чтения файла. А на счёт MemoryStream помочь не могу, т.к. C# не владею, а в Java такого стрима нет.